# Load Interstitial Ad in anctivity

Tags: android, interstitial

In my app, after integrating Interstitial Ad, ads are loading fine.

Now i want that the activity where the ad is showing should not display ad every-time when the user is opening the activity otherwise it will be annoying for the user to use the app.

For the same user, if he is opening that activity then the ratio should be suppose if the user is opening the activity 5 times then 2 times he should see the ad.

Is this possible to implement. kindly suggest

Comment: interstitial ads are very intrusive and will annoy the user regardless of how often you show them

Comment: Yes it possible but needs to be managed from your end, interstitial ad format do not provide what you want.

Comment: @VirRajpurohit   any hint of "to be managed from your end"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare `public static int count=0;`in activity where you start your intent to go in activity where you want to show ad

now put this code

```
you__activityname_where_count_declare.count++;

if(you__activityname_where_count_declare.count==5)
  {
    you__activityname_where_count_declare.count=0;
    your_ad_method.ShowInterstitialAds();
  }
```

it will show 1 time ad in 5 time visit

Comment: this is wrong and users will irritate go to  admob and do from there how many ads in 1 minute 1 day

Comment: how it is wrong..?, we requesting ad only if user visit this activity 5 time simple coding ,nothing illegal with admob

Answer (score 1):

If you are using admob than itis possible to set rates directly from ad block settings under advanced settings. This will save you hasles of coding rates

Comment: How does he or she accomplish this? Please add this to your answer

Answer (score 0):

open AdMob account and  you can set from there how many ads you want to display at particular time
[image]